# A bound on the number of partial transversals of a latin square

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, latin-square

A *Latin Square* (LS) of order $n$ is an $n$ on $n$ matrix, each entry contains one of the symbols $1,2,\ldots,n$, and every row and every column contains each symbol exactly once. A (complete) *Transversal* in a Latin square is a collection of $n$ entries of the Latin square with exactly one appearance for each row, each column, and each symbol. For some $k = 1,\ldots,n$, a *partial transversal* of size $k$ is a collection of $n$ entries of the Latin square with exactly one appearance for each row and each column such that exactly $k$ symbols appear in the collection (equivalently for the discussion here, it can be defined over a collection of size $k$ with distinct symbols). An equivalent point of view is a complete bipartite graph with $n$ vertices of each side, where each edge is colored in one of $n$ colors, such that the edges adjacent to each vertex are exactly one edge from each of the $n$ colors. In this formulation, a transversal is called a *rainbow matching*.

**Question:** I am interested, as part of my research, in finding a Latin square with as few as possible partial transversals of size more than $n/2$, which is half of the size of a complete transversal. Formally, for some $n \geq 1$ and a Latin square $L$ of order $n$, define $a(L)$ as the number of partial transversals in $L$ of size more than $n/2$. Define $a_n$ as the minimum value of $a(L)$ over all Latin squares $L$ of order $n$. What is the best upper bound we can get on $a_n$?

Note that it is irrelevant if the Latin square that satisfies the bound has a complete transversal or not; indeed, it is conjectured that every Latin square either has a transversal or a partial transversal with size $n-1$ and thus this does not seem to affect the bound considered in this question.

Comment: $>n/2$ or $ \ge n/2$?

Comment: I meant > n/2 but it should not be very important either way.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some results for small $n$, obtained via integer linear programming.

$a_1 = 1$:
\begin{matrix}
1 \\
\end{matrix}

$a_2 = 0$:
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}

$a_3 = 3$:
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 1 \\
3 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{matrix}

$a_4 = 8$:
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 1 & 4 & 3 \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}

$a_5 = 107$:
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
3 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 4 \\
2 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\
5 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}

$a_6 = 432$:
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
4 & 1 & 6 & 3 & 2 & 5 \\
6 & 5 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 3 \\
3 & 6 & 5 & 2 & 1 & 4 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 1 \\
5 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{matrix}

$a_7 \le 4151$:
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 1 \\
3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
6 & 7 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
7 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\end{matrix}

You could get a general upper bound for $a_n$ by counting partial traversals in the pattern that is illustrated for $n=7$.  (This pattern is not optimal for $n\in\{4,5,6\}$).

Comment: Hey thank you for the effort. I do not understand though how can I get a general upper bound on $a_n$ for a general $n$ via the details on $n = 7$.

Comment: Every Latin square for a given $n$ provides an upper bound for that $n$.  Computing the number of partial traversals in this "striped" pattern would yield an upper bound on $a_n$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easy of of computing such an upper bound on this "striped" pattern for a general $n$? I mean something combinatorial without using a computer.

Comment: I don't know an easy way, but the counts for small $n$ are $$1,0,
3,
16,
115,
468,
4151,
30208,
329589$$